# fatal error Index out of range

Tags: xcode, swift

I cannot understand where is mistake. Please help me to resolve this problem.

This is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class EncounterManager {
    let encounterNames: [String] = ["EncounterName1",
                                    "EncountersName2",
                                    "EncountersName3"]
    var encounters: [SKNode] = []

    var currentEncounterIndex:Int?

    var previousEncounterIndex:Int?


    init() {
        for encounterFileName in encounterNames {
            let encounter = SKNode()
            if let encounterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: encounterFileName) {
                for placeholder in encounterScene.children {

                    if let node = placeholder as? SKNode {

                        switch node.name! {
                        case "N" :
                            let n = N()
                            n.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "NN":
                            let nn = NN()
                            nn.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "NNN":
                            let nnn  = NNN()
                            nnn.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "GGG":
                            let ggg = GGG()
                            ggg.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "GG":
                            let gg = GG()
                            gg.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "G":
                            let g = G()
                            g.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        case "F":
                            let f = F()
                            ff.spawn(encounter, position: node.position)

                        default:
                            print("Name error: \(node.name)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    func addToWorld(world:SKNode) {

        for index in (encounters.count).stride(through: 0, by: -1) {

            encounters[index].position = CGPoint(x: -2000, y: index * 1000)
            world.addChild(encounters[index])

       }

   }

}
```

This is error from console:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

This is line in which error:

```
encounters[index].position = CGPoint(x: -2000, y: index * 1000)
```

This is line error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I tried to find some information about this problem in Internet, but can't find it.

Comment: *Hint:* What is index of the last element in an  array with `count` elements?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
for index in (encounters.count).stride(through: 0, by: -1)
```

To this:

```
for index in (encounters.count.predecessor()).stride(through: 0, by: -1)
```

You get the error because using the first version the stride begins from `encounters.count` which is one behind the last valid index.

Comment: Or: `for index in encounters.indices.reverse() ...`

Comment: @Viktor Simkó It help to fix it in first file, but now I have this error in another file. 
In line: ` encounterManager.encounters[0].position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 30)`

Comment: @MartinR It help to fix it in first file, but now I have this error in another file. In line: ` encounterManager.encounters[0].position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 30)`